# concatenar arrays java

Tags: java, array

Me han pedido que una dos arrays, he encontrado esta herramienta `(int[])ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b)` que en una sola línea lo puedo resolver. El problema es que me da error el compilador

> C:\Users\BEEO\Desktop\java\practica3>javac Vector.java
>   .\OperacionVectores.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
>            int[] c= (int[])ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b);
>                           ^   symbol:   variable ArrayUtils   location: class OperacionVectores 1 error

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class OperacionVectores{
public int[] ConcatV(int[] a, int[] b){
    int[] c= (int[])ArrayUtils.addAll(a, b);
    return c;

 }

}
```

muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: revisa list y arrays, estudia las diferencias

Comment: ok thx, le doy a eso

Comment: Estás usando [`ArrayUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) que pertenece a la Apache Commons y no viene incluida por defecto en el JDK.

Answer (score 6):

Ese método que estás usando pertenece a la [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll-int:A-int...-) y **no está disponible en el JDK**. Por eso el compilador no lo encuentra.

Te pongo un método que sí valdría en Java base:

```
public int[] concatV(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int[] result = new int[left.length + right.length];

    System.arraycopy(left, 0, result, 0, left.length);
    System.arraycopy(right, 0, result, left.length, right.length);

    return result;
}
```

Utiliza [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) que internamente comprueba que estás usando un array e itera copiando los valores.

---

Otra forma de hacerlo **a partir de Java 8** es utilizar la api de [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
public int[] concatV2(int[] left, int[] right) {
    return IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(left), IntStream.of(right)).toArray();
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya arregle el codigo, por decirlo de alguna forma xD, ya que copie el tuyo xDDDD, muchas gracias